# DelayedJob breaking validates unique constraints in ActiveRecord

Tags: activerecord, delayed-job, race-condition

This is pretty simple, I'm running a crawler that finds Cogs.  Cogs can belong to one single Widget.  Sometimes it finds a bunch of Cogs that all should belong to the same Widget. In the Cog model it runs:

```
# Find or create widget
match = Widget.where("name ILIKE (?)", name).first
match = Widget.create(name: name) unless match
```

The delayed jobs that run all at parallel are essentially like this:

```
- CREATE Cog, name: "cog1", (Widget, name: "Foo")
- CREATE Cog, name: "cog2", (Widget, name: "Foo")
- CREATE Cog, name: "cog3", (Widget, name: "Foo")
- CREATE Cog, name: "cog4", (Widget, name: "Foo")
```

This is unavoidable, but I thought would be handled by the match code above.  I also have this in the Widget model:

```
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

Unfortunately, with 4 DelayedJob workers running across 4 cores these jobs run at exactly the same time, causing multiple Widgets to be created despite both of the checks.  How do I prevent the race conditions when creating Widgets so I don't get duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the unique check and the insert are performed separately, there is a race condition. You need an index to enforce the uniqueness constraint.

The docs mention this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Comment: The database index will solve the problem of duplicate records being created, but they will raise errors because code will still be running at the same time and only the database will prevent insertion. I'd like a solution at application level, not database level. Maybe ActiveRecord transactions?